# AEM does not deploy new code into author server

Tags: java, aem

My project **AEM** working normal. But sometime, it can not update my new code by cmd:
`mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage`
In case html, I checked on CRXDE, my new code updated. `/apps/myproject/components/content/explore/explore.html`
But when I call this component, it work incorrectly with my new code.
If I get a new **AEM** and build my code, it will run corectly.

Edit: I guess some issue is **debug mode** because when I turn on server by debug mode and build source code, it will be work incorrectly with my new code.

Somebody help me fix this problem!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Check the logs under /crx-quickstart/logs, especially the error.log and see if there are error messages when your code is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

In all of your pom.xml files make sure the version has -SNAPSHOT on the end e.g. `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`
AEM wont overwrite certain files/bundles etc if they are the same version.

Comment: Thank Sutty, but in all of my pom.xml already had -SNAPSHOT: `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing should not happen. If the component code is successfully deployed to CRX/de, then AEM will for sure use it.

Make sure to check your content. For example, it may be that the content is not including the correct component/version.